# How to call (filter-) valueGetter functions for external filter in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag-grid with angular and I want to apply an external filter to it.
The [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/) shows an example what the `doesExternalFilterPass` function can look like:

```
function doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
  switch (ageType) {
    case 'below30': return node.data.age < 30;
    ...
    default: return true;
  }
}
```

It basically uses the raw data to filter the rows. As I use the columns valueGetter/filterValueGetter functions to modify the values, I want the external filter to filter based on the return values of these functions but I haven't found the proper way to do this.

I can get the value that I want by calling
`this.gridOptions.api.getValue(columnId, node);`
(which calls the valueGetter under the hood) instead of
`node.data[columnId]`
but I didn't find any example doing it that way.

So I am asking for the right way of calling the valueGetter functions inside `doesExternalFilterPass` or how anybody else approached this problem.

(It is especially important when you have rows that are not even included in the data object. This is the case when a columns values are calculated through a valueGetter/filterValueGetter function e.g. by adding two other columns.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `valueGetter`, you can add a custom field to your data model that you compute before feeding data to the grid. You will need to pre-process the data and then use this new field in column definition and external filter.

Comment: Although this solution doesn't make use of the `valueGetter` function, it is a viable alternative.

Comment: could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450872/search-function-of-agsetcolumnfilter-customization